# Delete file after 60seconds from gcs using Node js

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-storage

Here is the code to delete file but dont know how to delete it after certain time as there is no way in documentation.

```
 // Delete content file
     var fileToBeDeleted = null
     fileToBeDeleted = bucket.file(baseContentUrl)
     
     await fileToBeDeleted.delete()
```

Comment: What do you mean? Will the file be deleted after executing your code or is it based on the time uploaded to the bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var fileToBeDeleted = bucket.file(baseContentUrl);

setTimeout(async () => {
  await fileToBeDeleted.delete()
  // Do something after deleting.
}, 60 * 1000);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can we make it delete after 30 mins by making 1800 * 1000 ??

Comment: Yes @ShivamRishi

Comment: Tried by making 1800*1000 but not working

Comment: setTimeout is a javascript function, I'm totally positive that works (1800 * 1000), where are you running this? on a google cloud function?

Comment: You are not restarting the app before that line runs?, setTimeout should not block the app exit so if for some reason the app doesn't have anything else to execute, it will finish, even if the setTimeout is pending

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileToBeDeleted = null;
var numberofMiliseconds = 60 * 1000;
fileToBeDeleted = bucket.file(baseContentUrl);
setTimeout(async () => {
  //you can do any operation you want to do after 60 section this line will execute.
  await fileToBeDeleted.delete();
}, numberofMiliseconds);
```